# Python post-class-construction hook

Tags: python, class, constructor, initialization

I have a need to run some code at class creation time, invoking a function (in this case it happens to be a method) that I need to pass the `cls` class object and a few other things (mostly defined in the parent).

My solution so far is this:

```py
@PostConstruct()
class Child(Parent):
    X = 1
    Y = Parent.A
    Z = 2

    @classmethod
    def __post_construct__(cls):
        cls.add_thing(cls.X, as_key=True, before=cls.Y)
        cls.add_thing(cls.Z, as_key=False, before=cls.Y)
```

Supporting code:

```py
class PostConstruct:
    """
    Runs a class's ``__post_construct__`` class method immediately after
    the body code of the class is run.  Allows an author to make small
    modifications to the class (e.g. modifying class-level variables) at
    class creation time.
    """
    def __call__(self, cls):
        cls.__post_construct__()
        return cls

class Parent:
    A = 0

    @classmethod
    def add_thing(cls, thing, as_key, before):
        print("Adding thing...")
```

Is there some built-in post-class-construction hook method I've overlooked, so I wouldn't need to write this decorator myself?  I've looked at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation but I haven't seen anything that seems relevant.  But this wouldn't be the first time I've implemented some "clever" thing and then learned later that I could have done it simpler.

Or any other suggestion to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Metaclasses can do this, but if you don't need their functionality, the decorator is usually the better way to go (implementing a metaclass can limit the ability to do class mix-ins). I'm assuming you're not applying this to a hierarchy of classes (so `__init_subclass__` is not relevant). I will say, there is no reason to make `PostConstruct` a class; `def PostConstruct(cls):` as a plain function at top-level saves pointlessly constructing instances with no state just to immediately use their `__call__` and then discard the instance.

Comment: @ShadowRanger in fact I *used to* use `__init_subclass__` for this, but then I realized that it gets called once per *proper subclass*, and I want it to be called just for this class (which may never have subclasses).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I mean, maybe a mixin class that just defines an `__init_subclass__` would be another reasonable approach, but I agree, the simplest thing is just the decorator but defined as a function, not a pointless class

Comment: @KenWilliams as an aside, you shouldn't define your own dunder methods. Just call it `_post_construct`

Comment: Another aside, this looks incorrect: `def add_thing(thing, as_key, before):` you should use `staticmethod` if you mean to use it like a static method

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga very true, my real code uses `@classmethod` there, I'll fix that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, all.  Putting together the suggested tweaks from the comments, here's how I'm moving forward:

```py
@post_construct()
class Child(Parent):
    X = 1
    Y = Parent.A
    Z = 2

    @classmethod
    def _post_construct(cls):
        cls.add_thing(cls.X, as_key=True, before=cls.Y)
        cls.add_thing(cls.Z, as_key=False, before=cls.Y)
```

Supporting code:

```py
def post_construct(cls):
    """
    Runs a class's ``_post_construct`` class method immediately after the body code of the class is run.  Allows an author to make
    small modifications to the class (e.g. modifying class-level variables) at class creation time.
    """
    cls._post_construct()
    return cls

class Parent:
    A = 0

    @classmethod
    def add_thing(cls, thing, as_key, before):
        print("Adding thing...")
```